# How to run cosmos application

Tags: c#

I have used following code (cosmos + Visual Studio 2008) but on pressing `F5` application does not run, rather it provides an error: "microsoft visual studio has encountered an error and need to be close"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
namespace cosmos.user.kernel
{
    public class program
    {
   public static void Init()
   {
            Cosmos.Sys.Boot xBoot = new Cosmos.Sys.Boot();
            xBoot.Execute();
         //Main();
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            // Boot the Cosmos kernel:
            Cosmos.Compiler.Builder.BuildUI.Run();
            //Cosmos.Sys.Boot xBoot = new Cosmos.Sys.Boot();
            //xBoot.Execute();

            Console.WriteLine("Cosmos booted successfully. Type a line of text to get it echoed back:");
            string xResult = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Text typed: ");
            Console.WriteLine(xResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Test if you can run other applications!

Comment: i can run program on visual studio2008..but this is just a simple program...n not running:-(

Answer (score 0):

Since Cosmos is a different operating system, Visual Studio might have issues with trying to debug this thing.

I'd check what [Cosmos FAQ](http://cosmos.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ) and figure out what to do. Browsing the FAQ myself, I see the following disclaimer:

> **What version of Visual Studio can I
>   use to develop Cosmos?**
>
> Currently we
>   only support Visual Studio 2008. We
>   plan to support Visual Studio 2010 in
>   the future, but right now we have more
>   important features to complete.

Also, I notice in their Wiki that some folks have had a crashing bug with the VS 2008 integration.